# UIPopoverPresentationController displaying popover as full screen

Tags: ios, swift, popover, uipopover

I am trying to use `UIPopoverPresentationController` to display a `popover` that doesn't take up the whole screen. I've followed many different tutorials with no luck.

Here is my code. It correctly instantiates the `ViewController`, but it takes up the entire screen instead of just a smaller screen as I defined in `preferredContentSize`.

```
func showPopover() {
    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PopupTimePickerViewController") as PopupTimePickerViewController
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
    vc.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(200, 100)

    if let presentationController = vc.popoverPresentationController {
        presentationController.delegate = self
        presentationController.permittedArrowDirections = .Up
        presentationController.sourceView = self.view
        presentationController.sourceRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)

        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

**Update 9/27/16 with correct answer**

```
func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController, traitCollection: UITraitCollection) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return .none
}
```

Comment: @gabbler Nope. Only on the simulator. Don't have an iPhone to test it on.

Comment: Please try the answer. Don't forget to implement `adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController` method.

Comment: For me the problem was that, calling the PopoverViewController through a "PerformSegue" was always leaving it Full Screen. Deleting the storyboard segue and manually assembling it and showing through presentViewController solved it.

Comment: Update saved me.  Was stuck for +6 hours

Answer (score 44, accepted):

In iPhone, you should add the following in order to present a popover.

```
func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController!) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    // Return no adaptive presentation style, use default presentation behaviour
    return .None
}
```

Comment: Where do you add this? To the view controller of the Popover?

Comment: @Noah, to the view controller that presents the Popover, `self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)`, the controller `self`  represents.

Comment: On Swift 4, this won't give an error, but just won't fix the issue. Slight signature tweak:

`func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
        return UIModalPresentationStyle.none
    }`

Comment: Yes, and in order for it to be called, you need to set the calling view controller as the delegate to the popover's presentationController, as explained in other answers. Then you can look at the protocol definition for the appropriate signature. Xcode should autocomplete with the right one if you've set up the delegate properly.

Answer (score 20):

For Swift3/IOS10, looks like we need to do some thing like

```
func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController, traitCollection: UITraitCollection) -> UIModalPresentationStyle
{
    return .none
}
```

Adding this answer, in case, someone runs into this problem as i did when migrating to swift3/IOS10

Answer (score 7):

For Swift3+/IOS10+, when dealing with iPhone:

You must add **UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate** the delegate at:

```
class YourClass:  UIViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate { ...
```

Then implement in this same parent class (which will show the popover) the method below.

```
func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController, traitCollection: UITraitCollection) -> UIModalPresentationStyle
{
    return .none
}
```

And then set the popover configuration below:

```
myPopover.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
myPopover.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = VIEWTOPOINTTHEARROW.frame
myPopover.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
myPopover.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self
```

Also you may set some configuration for the popover class

```
 class MyPopover: UIViewController {

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //popover size
    self.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 320, height: 200) 
    //sets the arrow of the popover to same color of background
    self.popoverPresentationController?.backgroundColor = self.view.backgroundColor
   }

 }
```

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer is correct. For completeness, see [Adapting Presented View Controllers to a New Style](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/BuildinganAdaptiveInterface.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH32-SW6) in the Apple docs:

> Use the delegate’s `adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController:` method to specify a different presentation style than the default. When transitioning to a compact environment, the only supported styles are the two full-screen styles or `UIModalPresentationNone`. Returning `UIModalPresentationNone` tells the presentation controller to ignore the compact environment and continue using the previous presentation style. In the case of a popover, ignoring the change gives you the same iPad-like popover behavior on all devices.

Make sure that the required configurations from [Presenting a View Controller in a Popover](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/PresentingaViewController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH14-SW13) are met:

> After setting the modal presentation style [of the presented view controller] to `UIModalPresentationPopover`, configure the following popover-related attributes:
>
> - Set the `preferredContentSize` property of your view controller to the desired size.
> - Set the popover anchor point using the associated `UIPopoverPresentationController` object, which is accessible from the
>     view controller’s `popoverPresentationController` property.
> - Set only one of the following:
>
>   - Set the `barButtonItem` property to a bar button item.
>   - Set the `sourceView` and `sourceRect` properties to a specific region in one of your views.

Answer (score 0):

## iOS 12 / Swift 4

There's also the possibility to show the popover on IPhone's as fullscreen and on IPad's as a popover.

Just return `.popover` for `adaptivePresentationStyle()`:

```
func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return .popover
}
```

and set the popover-configuration like @mourodrigo did:

```
dialog.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
dialog.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self
dialog.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection(rawValue: 0)
dialog.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = view
dialog.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = view.frame
```

Answer (score 0):

objective-c version:

```
- (UIModalPresentationStyle)adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController:(UIPresentationController *)controller {
    return UIModalPresentationNone;
}
```