# Display popover as full screen for iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, uipopovercontroller

I am trying to use `UIPopoverPresentationController` to display a popover that doesn't take up the whole screen. already checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27353691/uipopoverpresentationcontroller-displaying-popover-as-full-screen) and other tutorials, but don't worked.

Here my code:

```
  @IBAction func temp(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "StayView", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "StayViewPopOverViewController") as! StayViewPopOverViewController

    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
    vc.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 180, height: 75)

    let popover = vc.popoverPresentationController!
    popover.sourceView = self.btnTemp
    popover.sourceRect = self.btnTemp.bounds
    popover.delegate = self
    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

My delegate method:

```
 func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController!) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return .none
}
```

but that cover Whole screen.
I tried to put breakpoint on delegate method but interpreter didn't stop on that.

can anyBody have any solution or any suggetions?

**Upated:**  I want to achieve like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I Got the answer.
Just need to update my delegate method like this:

```
 func adaptivePresentationStyle(
    for controller: UIPresentationController,
    traitCollection: UITraitCollection)
    -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
        return .none
}
```

Thats It... Works Great!!!

Answer (score 0):

Update following lines

```
 vc.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
 vc.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 180, height: 75)
```

with

```
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
vc.preferredContentSize = view.frame.size
```

Comment: gives nil error on  ` let popover = vc.popoverPresentationController!`

Comment: and I dont want full Screen

Comment: then what you want, can you please update question so will give proper answer

Comment: I just want popOver with size of (width: 180, height: 75)