# Swift | UIViewController not showing as PopUp but Fullscreen

Tags: swift, popup, uipopovercontroller, popupwindow, modalviewcontroller

So i have a viewcontroller which is basically an alert window which is supposed to be a popup and be dismissed by the tap on outside its frame.

But whenever i call that VC, it is always displayed as fullscreen and not as a pop up window.

I have tried a couple of ways to do this, namely as mentioned below.

```
 if let exp : String = expiredVehicles[i] {
        expiredVehicleNumber = expiredVehicles[i]
            let popUpVC = SubscriptionExpired()
            popUpVC.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
            popUpVC.modalPresentationStyle = .popover // also tried other presentation styles but none work and it is still fullscreen
            popUpVC.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.8)
            self.present(popUpVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
```

in case anyone need to see the definition of that VC, i will be glad to share it

i feel i should mention that the VC to be displayed as a popup is inheriting UIViewController

Any insight that might help would be great.

Thanks for the input

Comment: Can you show the screenshot or change popover to overCurrentContext

Comment: You can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26598099/present-uiviewcontroller-as-a-modal-with-transparent-background

Comment: @AtalayAsa i went through it and made the presentation style to custom and still fullscreen, should i put frame or something? because i am trumped

Comment: So you are using an iPad right?

Comment: @wings overCurrentContext was the first one i tried and it was no luck either, any other ideas? maybe i should give the frame?

Comment: @AhmadF currently i am trying it out in iphoneXR in simulator, does it matter, should i get a physical iphone 6?

Answer (score 0):

One potential way is to add a tap gesture recognizer to your View, which dismisses the VC.

But this will only be helpful if this popup has read-only info and doesn't require any further action from the user.

```
func addTapRecognizer(){
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleTap))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

@objc func handleTap(){
       // dismiss the VC here
    }
}
```

Comment: yes i am aware of this solution but this is more like a workaround and not sure if my employer will allow it. also the problem is that VC has a button as well which will redirect to customer helpline page so if i add tap gesture to the whole view, that button will stop working

Answer (score 0):

You can call following method to show popup:

```
    let popupVC = SubscriptionExpired()
    popupVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    self.addChild(popupVC)
    popupVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
    self.view.addSubview(popupVC.view)
    popupVC.didMove(toParent: self)
}
```

Then, for removing that popup you can use:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
    self.view.alpha = 0.0
}, completion: { (finished) in
    if finished {
        self.view.removeFromSuperview()
    }
})
```

In that case I have a button inside popup and whenever that button pressed above method triggers. Can you please try it? I can edit my answer according to your needs.

Comment: brother, everything in this app is done completely programatically, no storyboard or interface builder is being used anywhere, so i dont think this will be of any help....or would it?

Comment: It's okay even if your app is done programmatically, you can use these methods like `let popupVC = PopupVC()` and show that view controller.

Comment: ok i will give it a shot, but where should i declare the type of my VC to be presented. keep in my mind i am still an amateur at swift

Comment: no luck either brother, now the VC is fullscreen but the UITabbar is visible but still dont go away, when i add the second part of the code to dismiss, it just turn whole view to black screen but uitabbar still visible

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement this in you presenting view controller:

```
func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    // Return no adaptive presentation style, use default presentation behaviour
    return .none
}
```

[UIPopoverPresentationController displaying popover as full screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27353691/uipopoverpresentationcontroller-displaying-popover-as-full-screen)